# Django: How do I use a foreign key field in aggregation?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following two models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    factor = models.DecimalField(...)
    ... other fields

class Child(models.Model):
    field_a = models.DecimalField(...)
    field_b = models.DecimalField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    ... other fields
```

Now I want to calculate the sum of `(field_a * field_b * factor)` of all objects in the `Child` model. I can calculate the sum of `(field_a * field_b)` with `aggregate(value=Sum(F('field_a')*F('field_b'), output_field=DecimalField()))`. My question is how I can pull out the `factor` field from the `Parent` model?

I am new to Django and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django let's you follow relationships with the double underscore (__) as deep as you like. So in your case `F('parent__factor')` should do the trick.

The full queryset:

```
Child.objects.aggregate(value=Sum(F('field_a') * F('field_b') * F('parent__factor'), output_field=DecimalField()))
```